# How to get CSS dynamically changed value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a div that when i hover a link it keeps animating the div to the left using `.animate()` and when mouseout it stops the animation.

When it animates, it adds a `style="left:x"` to the div, where x is the actual value.

Im trying to get this value but its not working.

I've tried this:

```
var posicao = $('#conteudo').css('left');

$('a').click(function(e)({
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(posicao);
});
```

but its returning the value `auto`. In css file i didnt even set a value to `left`..

In fact I have two questions.

- How to get this value?
- Why is it returning `auto` if i didnt even set a value to left?

EDIT*** 
here's the link http://www.estudiocaju.com.br/homolog/dicavalcanti/teste/
Theres 2 black bars on left and right. if you hover them itll `.animate()` the `#conteudo` section. If you click the `<header>` area it'll `console.log(posicao)`

Comment: You probably want to get div `position` http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: Can you show us the code inside the animation method?

Comment: Should'nt you already know what values you are animating to ?

Comment: Are you sure that you apply the left-property to the correct element, or that you read the correct element? have you checked in your inspector that everything is being applied correctly? because .css('left') is correct. The problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: when i put `.position()` instead `.css()` it returns `Object {top: 0, left: 0}`.

Comment: adeneo, no. i have to get this value dynamically changed by the `.animate()`

Comment: `Allendar` ill post it on a link, 1min.

Comment: I added the link on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var posicao = $('#conteudo').position().left;
```

?

P.S.: And you should use this inside the click event otherwise the value will be stored on document load , when it will always be 0. Something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e)({
    e.preventDefault();
    var posicao = $('#conteudo').position().left;
    console.log(posicao);
});
```